# Is it a good idea to dynamically create actions and reducers for redux with react-native?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm new to react-native and redux and I'm creating an app that consists of a survey page and a main page that would display other users depending on how they answered the survey. I use firebase to take care of user authentication and to save the results of the survey and redux to handle the state. I started with hardcoding each question and input field then each question has its own action and reducer to update the state on each change from the user (such as typing a letter for the first/last name field).

The survey component has grown to a point where I was considering using firebase to store all the questions and answers and having the component fetch the data then generate the survey. However, since I'm using redux I'm not sure what the process is for dynamically creating actions and reducer or if that would even be a good option. My thought process for using redux was that all my pages could grab the data from the global state since they aren't connected through a parent/child relationship and I use react-native-router-flux to navigate between pages.

TL:DR: I want to store questions and answers to a survey in firebase and have my component fetch the data and create the questions but I'm not sure what the best practice is for saving the state if I want to use redux since I want other pages to have access to this data.